# Why does the impeller of a torque converter sit behind the turbine?

Tags: theory, torque-converter

i saw this picture of a Chrysler A-727 TorqueFlite and it shows that the impeller actually comes after the turbine. Why is it done like this? Doesn't it make more sense to put the impeller before the turbine since the engine rotates the impeller? Why go to the trouble of putting the impeller behind the turbine?
[image: labelled diagram of TorqueFlite transmission and torque converter]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the design, you can see the input shaft of the transmission goes all the way through the torque converter and sits in the front part where the turbine is. The splined part at the input shaft engages the turbine. The stator sits behind it (towards the transmission), which is attached to the TC shell. If this was done in reverse, stability would be sacrificed and the transmission input shaft would wear out quicker because there would be basically nothing supporting the turbine except the end of the input shaft. With it all the way through, the input shaft only needs to spin and is supported at both ends. I would lay wager the fluid could be made flow with either setup and work. This just makes more sense structurally.

Comment: i see thanks, so im guessing in this case in the picture in the link https://tankautomotives.files.wordpress.com/2023/01/leo1.png since TC is nowhere near the engine it will suffer in terms of stability and have less lifetime compared to the layout of torqueflite right? In this picture "antrieb" means the engine , P means Pumpenrad (impeller) , L means leitrad (stator) , T means turbine. So in this case the impeller comes first then stator then turbine and TC itself is nowhere near the engine.

Comment: @TimothyScherer - In the image you linked, there appears to be a rod which goes completely through the  TC, which would give everything support. It connects the left and right "Abtrieb" together. The difference is, the engine is combined at the front of the transmission and power is sent backwards, through a gear, re-oriented 90° to match the transmission orientations, then fed into the TC. If you look at it the TC it is setup the same way, with P (impeller) attached to the TC outer shell, L (stator) in between, and the P (impeller) attached to the output where it attaches to the drive.

Comment: ahh yeah i see now thanks a lot. I guess i should fix a couple sentences in that blog that i wrote now that i learned whats actually going on with that layout of TC. Also Here is link to whole blog if you are interested https://tankautomotives.wordpress.com/2023/01/09/leopard-1-transmission-and-steering-unit-zf-4hp-250-explained/